# How to inspect chrome UI with GTK inspector?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, user-interface

I would like to make an app that manipulate one Chrome extension automatically.
Unfortunately there is no any programmable interface to do it.

So, To achieve it, I have to inspect UI element of Chrome (Not Web content, It is part of Chrome's UI like menu bar and so on..)

But when I have tried inspect chrome UI with GTK inspect tool, the tool be gone when I click an element of UI with "Select an object".

Does GTK inspector has support of Google chrome, if Chrome is supported, how I can "select an object" to Chrome?